# Passing text area values to another page

Tags: php, html

page1.php

```
<form action ="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<form action ="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?> />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Hi all, this is working OK but when I go to `page2.php` the saved value in the text box is reading `jason /><input type=` I have tried various things trying to remove `/><input type=` Can any shed some light on my error? Cheers...CPM

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" />
```

You forgot the closing quote for value attribute.

Comment: Doh! Need my eyes checked I think. Cheers KA.

Comment: Dont forget to mark Abishek's answer as the correct answer